# Fetching upcoming iTunes album releases

Tags: itunes

I would like to track album releases for a group of artists. I could just loop over all of them and check to see if they have any releases since the last one, but it would be much more efficient if I could select future releases.

How can I get anticipated releases via the iTunes API (or another one if this isn't possible)? I was thinking maybe preorders or there would be a list of upcoming releases for that week?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit obscure, but [iTunes actually offers email notifications for new releases](http://www.apple.com/itunes/inside-itunes/2011/06/get-email-alerts-when-your-favorite-artists-release-new-content.html) by artists you select. To add an artist to the list, go to the artist's page within iTunes, and click the *Alert Me* link in the right sidebar, then click *Manage My Alerts*.

You'll see the artist has been added to the list (it may also contain artists you've previously purchased music from). Check the *Send me email alerts about artists I've previously downloaded* box to (surprise) get email when they release something. To add more artists, click the *Alert Me* on their page, then click *OK*.

If you don't want to use email for this, iTunes offers [new release RSS feeds](http://itunes.apple.com/rss). You could filter these with something like [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) to get a feed with only the artists you're interested in.

It's worth noting that these both display new releases when they come out, not upcoming releases. As far as I can tell, Apple doesn't publish any upcoming release data, except for the [pre-orders page](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewMultiRoom?cc=ca&fcId=292454406), which doesn't seem to contain all upcoming releases, just featured ones.

Comment: Wow that is very cool! Do you know if there is a way to programmatically access these? The RSS feed only gives 300, but I would guess there would be a bunch that aren't included?

Comment: Well, it's an RSS feed, so it will update regularly with newer ones. RSS is just XML, so there are lots of ways to access it programmatically. Yahoo Pipes is sort of like Automator for the web, and deals with RSS well, so that might be worth a look. For more serious programming needs, pretty much any language has plenty of XML parsing libraries available. For more in-depth help with that, you'll probably want to head to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I track new releases of my favourite artist using free app in iTunes: [**Alerter**](http://alerterapp.mobi/download)

I subscribe for artists, when new releases will be available on iTunes I'll get push notifications. It works more faster and reliable than my alerts.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [getreleases.net](http://www.getreleases.net). It sends email notifications about new releases by artists you subscribed. Free, fast and simple.